# Commanline is not working to create a catkin workplace in Ubuntu 14.04 for ROS

Tags: linux, ubuntu-14.04, ros, catkin

I am actually a newbie in both ROS and Linux. For that, I am a bit struggling with all these kinds of stuff.

I was trying to make catkin workplace and initialize it using the following commands:

```
$ mkdir -p ~/catkin_ws/src
$ cd ~/catkin_ws/src
$ catkin_init_workspace
```

Before that I have added the system-wide ROS setup script to `.bashrc` file by:

```
$ source /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash
```

The terminal shows this:

```
$ source /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash
$ mkdir -p ~/catkin_ws/src
$ cd ~/catkin_ws/src
$ catkin_init_workplace
catkin_init_workplace: command not found
```

Struggling with the line 'command not found'. Why is this happening? How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have added ROS setup script to your `.bashrc`, you have to logout/login or, preferably, reboot the system. Once logged in again, the script will be automatically loaded and the additional catkin scripts will become visible.

You may check that with `which catkin_init_workspace` even without running it.